# Mediation, low R^2

Tags: interpretation, r-squared, mediation

I am currently working on my model in which I would like to test mediation effects.

In my model following applies
Y-company attractiveness 
X-type of application (digital vs nondigital) and 
M-perceived company competence in selecting suitable candidates.

For the path X=>M I am getting a p=0.1074 which can be questionable with the p=0.1 on top of this the $R^2$=0.011 in this path is very low. Other paths are all significant. Can this still be interpreted as mediation despite of such low $R^2$?

Comment: I would encourage you to read the section titled R^2 nuisance or distraction in this lecture note https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/10/lecture-10.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to interpret an effect as mediation using the linear SEM/path model formulation of mediation (i.e., in contrast to causal mediation) is for the product of the X -> M path and the M -> Y path to be different from zero in the population. The significance of any individual path is irrelevant to deciding if you have mediation. You have not mentioned whether this is the case in your analysis.

$R^2$ has nothing to do with whether mediation is taking place. $R^2$ has to do with how much of your outcome is explained by the predictors. It may be very low, but that doesn't mean that mediation isn't taking place; it just means the predictor (and mediator) don't explain much of the outcome. The question is about whether what is being explained is due to mediation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I was not specific enough. As suggested by Baron and Kenny(1986), I checked:
1. X= b0 + b1M + e, for b1 p=0,1074, r^2=1.2%
2. Y=b0 + b1X + e, for b1 p=0,06, r^2=1.5%
3. Y=b0 + b1X + b2M + e, for b1 p=0,32, for b2 p=0.00 r^2=53%
Im just surprised what happened with r^2 and if I can still assume that mediation is happening? I suspect that competence itself explains very well attractiveness due to the fact that it is an answer regarding entire recruitment process(3 stages) and I am trying to verify if for each of the stage competence is a mediation effect.

Comment: The Baron and Kenny approach is considered obsolete and has been abandoned by most mainstream social scientists. R2 has nothing to do with mediation. See DOI: [10.1146/annurev.psych.58.110405.085542] for an introduction to contemporary mediation analysis.